# Show that the following argument is valid (Discrete Math)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I'm stuck on a homework problem and would like some help understanding it. I have to show that the following argument is valid:

1. $q\to r$
2. $u\to (\def\osim{\mathord{\sim}}\osim t \vee v)$
3. $p\to\osim r$
4. $t \vee q$
5. $u \wedge p$

$\therefore$ $v$

I understand that rules of interference must be used, but I have no idea on how to use them. I don't necessarily want just a plain answer; I'd also like some insight as to how to do these kinds of problems. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: "Rules of interference" sound awkward, try "rules of inference" instead ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the statements you are given, the only hope of proving $v$ is to use $(2)$, showing that $u$ is true to get $\def\osim{\mathord{\sim}}\osim t\vee v$, and also showing $t$ is true, so $\osim t$ is false, so $v$ is true.  Now

- $u$ true is easy, it comes straight from $(5)$.
- $(5)$ also gives $p$ true, then $(3)$, $(1)$, $(4)$ give $r$ false, $q$ false, $t$ true and you are finished.

Perhaps you can put this together and supply the names of the rules of inference which you are using.